# boost/thread.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, boost, ubuntu-18.04

There are many similar posts with the same error what I am facing, but none of the solutions worked for me. Please do not think this as repeated. I am reaching you out after trying with all the solutions suggested.

I am trying to create a python library from c++ file that uses boost library with

> `#include <boost/thread.hpp>`

I have installed Boost in Ubuntu through the commands

> `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local`

and then

> `./b2 install --with-thread`

. 
Now, when I try to run a file with `#include <boost/thread.hpp>` it gives me this error saying

> src/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: boost/thread.hpp: No such file or directory

Am I missing on something? Can someone help me how can I solve this.

**Error**

I will attach a screenshot of the same for viewing. [image: BoostThread]

Also pasting the error description in-case someone does not feel comfortable to view image

```
  Failed building wheel for python-example  
  Running setup.py clean for python-example  
Failed to build python-example  
Installing collected packages: python-example  
  Running setup.py install for python-example ... error  
    Complete output from command /home/hmi/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c   "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-req-build-h4742spy  /setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',   open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record   /tmp/pip-record-3l3u7dxm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-  managed --compile:  
    running install  
    running build  
    running build_ext  
    gcc -pthread -B /home/hmi/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/hmi/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c /tmp/tmpbv27mdxm.cpp -o tmp/tmpbv27mdxm.o -std=c++17  
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++  
    gcc -pthread -B /home/hmi/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/hmi/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c /tmp/tmps2iqs0qp.cpp -o tmp/tmps2iqs0qp.o -fvisibility=hidden  
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++  
    building 'python_example' extension  
    creating build  
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7  
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src  
    gcc -pthread -B /home/hmi/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/hmi/anaconda3/include -I/home/hmi/anaconda3/include -I/home/hmi/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c src/main.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/main.o -DVERSION_INFO="0.0.1" -std=c++17   -fvisibility=hidden  
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++  
    src/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: boost/thread.hpp: No such file or directory  
     #include <boost/thread.hpp>  
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    compilation terminated.  
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have also tried with this command

> `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lpthread -lboost_system -lboost_thread -o main`

. But similar result.

**OS : Ubuntu 18.04**

**Boost version : 1.55**

Comment: Is there a good reason why you cannot simply use the system packages? `apt install libboost-thread-dev` (and likewise for other libraries you may need)

Comment: did you install boost-thread source code using `apt` ?

Comment: No.. I downloaded the file and did with bootstrap, ./b2. Using apt did not help me. Access Permission problem

Comment: Boost 1.55, do you know how old that is? Also, C++ has their own thread support, the one from Boost isn't necessary for modern C++ compilers.

Comment: 1. Where has `thread.hpp` been installed?  (`sudo updatedb` plus `locate thread.hpp` should tell you). 2. What is your include path (`g++ -E -Wp,-v -xc++ /dev/null`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now resolved it with the command mentioned by Botje but with sudo.

```
sudo apt install libboost-thread-dev
```

But I did not want to do through root. So I have refrained its usage. But now I did not find any other way. I would be glad to know if any other solution works

Comment: How did you install Boost in `/usr/local` without root privileges? In any case, using packages allows you to completely remove them again, which may not be as easy when messing around with your OS on the filesystem level. That said, you can install pretty much everything locally in your user's home directory without the need for root privileges. You will just have to tell the compiler where to find things and maybe configure the runtime linker to pick up stuff from there, too.